# Download video to temporary file from remote server and delete after forced download is finished

Tags: html, video, download, server

I am trying to download video from remote server and send it to html5 video play on the fly. I can download file but and send downloaded file to player.

I want to do this on the fly, I mean that I don't want to save whole file but save it temporary in chunks and send it to player then delete after video is watched.

Is it possible?

Thank you for your help.

```
<?php

$file = 'http://hostname.com/files/video.mp4';
copy($file,'./video.mp4');

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Besides copying the video? I feel you should research more and post what you have to increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: can you explain your scenario a bit better